# Android upload video + multiple images to Apache Tom cat java server?

Tags: android, tomcat

Is there any Server side coding plus android coding to upload multiple files to java server.

Comment: Yes there is. You just need to search for it on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But can you please provide some sample piece of code(Not using PHP).

Comment: Can Any one please share java server-side code for receiving the file send as part of this Mutipart Post?